# How to get text after the match REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I have string "my home" and regex: $reg = "/hom/" for example. I'm struggling to find out how can I get text after the match (until the end of word), in this case I'm looking for 'e'.

Another example:

`$string = 'soulful';
    $reg = '/soul/';`

=>>> I need 'ful'.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = 'soulful';
$reg = '/soul(\w+)/';
if ( preg_match($reg, $str, $m) )
   print_r ($m);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => soulful
    [1] => ful
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your regex to use a group with `(` and `)`:

```
$string = 'soulful';
$regex = '/soul(.+)/';
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(7) "soulful"
    [1]=> string(3) "ful"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expand your regex to match all text after original regex, ie:

```
$string = 'soulful';
$regex = '/soul(.*)/';
if ( preg_match($regex, $string, $match) ) {
 echo 'The text after soul is: '.$match[1].PHP_EOL;
}
```