# How to find a word in a file and get the characters next to it with php?

Tags: php, file

I have to make a chatroom using html, css and php for school.
Everything has to be saved in text files.
I'm trying to give all usernames in the chatroom colors. I saved
all usernames in a text file aswell as the colors in a different text file.

**chatusernames.txt**

miroh
hellevator

**usernamecolors.txt**

miroh RGB(219, 11, 11)
hellevator RGB(255, 11, 11)

I was able to get the name out of chatusernames.txt and now I have
to get the color from usernamecolors.txt.
I THINK I was able to compare the words and find the name but I don't know how to get the color next to it. I want to put the color in a simple string.

ex. I got miroh in usernamecolors.txt but can't get RGB(219,11,11) out of it.

I'm super new to using files with php and I hardly understand it. Please help me :(

```
               $usernamecolors = fopen($path . "usernamecolors.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
                $findname = true;
                while (!feof($usernamecolors)) {
                    $letter = fgetc($usernamecolor);
                    if ($letter != " " || $letter != ':') {
                        $findname = $findname + $letter;
                        if ($findname == $name) {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

My code is a mess sorry.
$name is the username taken out of usernames.txt and $findname is the name found in usernamecolors.txt 

I just need to know how to:
- Find a word in a file
- Add the characters next to it in a file

Comment: Might wel be easier to use a database

Comment: Would something like this with `regex` work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079478/how-to-get-text-after-the-match-regex

Comment: `+` is for math, not string concatenation.

Comment: Can you write `json` to the text file or create a `csv` file? It would remain a "text" file but then you could use key value paris...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading it bit by bit, this loads the whole file into an array using [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).  It then processes each line and splits it using [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), splitting it by space and limiting it to 2 elements will split something like `miroh RGB(219, 11, 11)` into `miroh` and `RGB(219, 11, 11)`.  It then uses the first part as the index to a new array and stores the color against it.

```
$usernamecolors = file($path . "usernamecolors.txt", 
    FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) 
        or die("Unable to open file!");
$colors = [];
foreach ( $usernamecolors as $line )    {
    list($name, $color) = explode(" ", $line, 2);
    $colors[$name] = $color;
}
```

If you then

```
print_r($colors);
```

You get...

```
Array
(
    [miroh] => RGB(219, 11, 11)
    [hellevator] => RGB(255, 11, 11)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would have used standard formats for the file like JSON, INI or CSV.

If you still wants to use a non standardly formatted file like you did, you can use [fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fgets.php) function to read the file line by line.

Once you got a line it's quite easy to get the name of a user and it's associated color.

EDIT : for string concatenation in PHP the `.` operator is used, not `+`

Answer (score 0):

you can use only chatusernames.txt and edited like this

miroh|RGB(219, 11, 11)

after that u just explode each line and have username and color separated for each user

```
$usernamecolors = fopen($path . "usernamecolors.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $users = [];
        while (!feof($usernamecolors)) {
            $line = fgets($usernamecolors);
            if (trim($line) != '') {
                $line = explode('|', $line);
                $users[] = ['username' => $line[0], 'color' => trim($line[1])];
            }
        }
```