# Get characters right after match in a foreach loop

Tags: php, regex

On my site I want to detect if someone mentions a username in a comment, like so: `what's up /u/username`.

How exactly can I extract the characters following `/u/` in a foreach loop?

Something like this:

```
if (strpos($commentString, '/u/') !== false) {
    foreach /u/ in $commentString {
        $username = the text immediately after /u/, stopping at anything that isn't a letter or a number
    }   
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079478/how-to-get-text-after-the-match-regex start with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all) with a regex of

```
/u/([a-z0-9]+)
```

to capture the usernames in the text. For example:

```
$text = "what's up /u/username have you seen /u/user21 today?";

preg_match_all('#/u/([a-z0-9]+)#i', $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $user) {
    echo "found user $user\n";
}
```

Output:

```
found user username
found user user21
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BKCC6)

Comment: Amazing! Out of curiosity, why is it $matches[1]? What's in [0]?

Comment: @FelixMaxime `$matches[1]` is the contents of capture group 1, which is `([a-z0-9]+)`, so just the username part of the regex. `$matches[0]` contains the *entire* match, so would include the `/u/` part as well.